# Ticker text jumping when infinite loop restarts with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've a simple scroll text ticker on a loop. However I'm having an issue with the loop jumping slightly as it cycles through in the jQuery.

I'm not sure how to set the Timeout so that its one smooth continuous cycle? I've tried changing `window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 10);` but it continuous to jump. I'm wondering if maybe this isn't the best way to do it?

```js
// polyfill
window.requestAnimationFrame = (function() {
  return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 10);
    };
})();

var speed = 5000;
(function ticker() {
  var tickeritemWidth = $('.ticker-item:first-child').outerWidth();
  $("#ticker").animate({
    marginLeft: -tickeritemWidth
  }, speed, 'linear', function() {
    $(this).css({
      marginLeft: 0
    }).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
  });
  requestAnimationFrame(ticker);
})();
```

```css
#ticker-wrapper {
  height: 10%;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

#ticker {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 1000%;
  margin: 0;
  background: red;
}

.ticker-item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 50px;
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-family: arial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="ticker-wrapper">
  <ul id="ticker">
    <li class="ticker-item">
      #mjhonjhedolls
    </li>
    <li class="ticker-item">
      @mjhonjhedolls
    </li>
    <li class="ticker-item">
      #mjhonjhedolls
    </li>
    <li class="ticker-item">
      @mjhonjhedolls
    </li>
    <li class="ticker-item">
      #mjhonjhedolls
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/695328/)

Comment: I'd look into [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) instead.

Comment: I looked into achieving this with CSS but the text didn't continuous loop, the text would disappear off the page before starting the loop again.

Comment: Personally i would do some research of how to avoid **setTimeout** as it has been known to cause issues and its one of the causes of a slow website this may be even causing the issue your having this is just a heads up :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below snippet and animation without using setTimeout,

```js
var speed = 5000;
(function ticker(){
    $('.ticker-item').each(function(index){
      var tickeritemWidth = $(this).outerWidth();
      $("#ticker").animate({marginLeft:-tickeritemWidth},speed, 'linear', function(){
        $(this).css({marginLeft:0}).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
      });
    });    
    ticker();
})();
```

```css
#ticker-wrapper {
  height: 10%;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

#ticker {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 1000%;
  margin: 0;
  background: red;
}

.ticker-item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 50px;
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-family: arial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="ticker-wrapper">
  <ul id="ticker">
    <li class="ticker-item">
      #mjhonjhedolls
    </li>
    <li class="ticker-item">
      @mjhonjhedolls
    </li>
    <li class="ticker-item">
      #mjhonjhedolls
    </li>
    <li class="ticker-item">
      @mjhonjhedolls
    </li>
    <li class="ticker-item">
      #mjhonjhedolls
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a CSS animation solution:

```css
#ticker-wrapper {
  height: 5rem;
  padding: 1.2rem 0 1rem;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-family: arial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#ticker {
  width: 48em;
  margin: 0;
  animation: marquee 8s linear infinite;
  position: absolute;
}

#ticker li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: pink;
  width: 12em;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: -24em;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="ticker-wrapper">
  <ul id="ticker">
    <li>
      #mjhonjhedolls
    </li><li>
      @mjhonjhedolls
    </li><li>
      #mjhonjhedolls
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately this doesn't work either, if you view your example in full page view you will see the jumpiness is still there and its not one continuous loop.

Comment: If the space is wider, you might have to add some `<li>`s and increase the `#ticker`'s width accordingly: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oPzyzv